# Extracting math operator from a String[] java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[3];
    args[1]="+";
    args[0]="8";
    args[2] = "5";
    if(args.length<3){
        System.out.println("Not enough arguments");
    } else if(args[1]!="+"&&args[1]!="-"&&args[1]!="*"&&args[1]!="/"){
        System.out.println("Don't equals basic math operators.Please iput j'+', '-' ,'*', '/'");
    }else if(!args[0].matches("[0-9]+")||!args[2].matches("[0-9]+")){
        System.out.println("Error. Please insert numeric value");
    }else {
        double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        char b = args[1].charAt(0);
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        System.out.println(a+b+c);

    }
```

a+b+c gives result of 56.0 insted of expexting result of 13.Can anybody explain where is my fault?
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `char` is a numeric type and what happens is that you're summing the value of `a`, the numeric value of `b`, and the value of `c`.

You have to create a new conditional statement. For example:

```
if (b == '-') {
    System.out.println(a - c);
} else if (b == '+') {
    System.out.println(a + c);
} else if (b == '*') {
    System.out.println(a * c);
} else if (b == '/') {
    System.out.println(a / c);
}
```

Also, you can take advantage of the `Java Scripting API`, instead of making complex conditional statements. The trick to represent the operation as a `String` and pass it to the `ScriptEngine#eval()` method.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
context.setWriter(writer);

engine.eval("print(" + a + b + c + ")");

String output = ;
System.out.println("Script result: " + writer.toString());
```